# Why event is trigger as soon as I click on the input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having the following HTML/jQuery code:

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  var manage_form_listing_grid = $("#manage_form_listing"),
    forms_search = $("#forms_search"),
    btn_search_forms = $("#btn_search_forms"),
    chk_show_archived = $("#show_archived"),
    inp_search_form_by_name = $("#search_form_by_name");

  forms_search.keypress(function(ev) {
    var key = ev.which;
    if (key === 13) {
      btn_search_forms.trigger("click");
      return false;
    }
  });

  forms_search.on("click", btn_search_forms, function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var archive = !!chk_show_archived.is(":checked");

    alert("You click me");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Search form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-inline" id="forms_search">
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="search_form_by_name" id="search_form_by_name" class="form-control input-full-width">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="show_archived" name="show_archived" value="1"> Show archived?
                </label>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_search_forms">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search
              </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_new_form">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Form
              </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why the click event is triggered as soon as I click on the `input#search_form_by_name`? What I am missing here? I would expect that clicking the button will trigger the event but not the click event on the input. Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/sharw595/)

Comment: Why are you trying to use event delegation here instead of just `btn_search_forms.on("click", function() { ... })` ?

Comment: @Turnip is not what I am using the right way to do it? I read somewhere (didn't have the source) a time ago that what I am using is the right way to use this, isn't?

Comment: The event should be handled by the element itself unless you are dynamically adding the element to the DOM after your events are bound (after making an AJAX call for example).

Comment: That makes sense, the element isn't added on the fly so if I am following you is safe to delegate the `on` event to the element itself and when it's created on the fly then delegate on it's parent.

Comment: That isn't delegation, that is simply adding listener directly to element exactly the way you did with `forms_search.keypress`

Comment: The simplest way is usually best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A delegated target of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) needs to be a selector string, not jQuery object

Change

```
forms_search.on("click", btn_search_forms, function(ev) {
```

To

```
forms_search.on("click", '#btn_search_forms', function(ev) {
```

Comment: I always forgot that the 2nd parameter is the selector and not the object :-\ thanks

Comment: @guradio no, it was me forgetting the syntax! not a typo at all

Comment: @guradio no, OP was passing object variable not selector as argument

Answer (score 1):

Since you've created separate variables for the elements you can call on() this way:

```
btn_search_forms.on('click', function(ev){...})
```

Or as it is mentioned above, change the second param to a string

```
forms_search.on('click', '#btn_search_forms', function(ev) {...})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  var manage_form_listing_grid = $("#manage_form_listing"),
    forms_search = $("#forms_search"),
    btn_search_forms = $("#btn_search_forms"),
    chk_show_archived = $("#show_archived"),
    inp_search_form_by_name = $("#search_form_by_name");
    var new_form = $("#btn_new_form");
  forms_search.keypress(function(ev) {
  debugger
    var key = ev.which;
    if (key === 13) {
      btn_search_forms.trigger("click");
      return false;
    }
  });

  forms_search.on("click", btn_search_forms, function(ev) {
  console.log(btn_search_forms);
console.log("#btn_search_forms");
    ev.preventDefault();

    var archive = !!chk_show_archived.is(":checked");

    alert("You click me");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Search form</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-inline" id="forms_search">
          <div class="form-group col-md-5">
            <input type="text" name="search_form_by_name" id="search_form_by_name" class="form-control input-full-width">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="show_archived" name="show_archived" value="1"> Show archived?
                </label>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_search_forms">
                <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Search
              </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn_new_form">
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> New Form
              </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Issue is the `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )` the issue is   selector here is a string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

So in your case selected elements is complete forms_search. So click is attach to complete as will matching  selector it didn't anything.

I have added console to check what is the value btn_search_form holding when click event trigger. See the difference. You are passing object but it need string.